# Disable other checkboxes in a GroupBox when two are checked

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

```
 Private Sub AllBoxes_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged, CheckBox5.CheckedChanged, CheckBox6.CheckedChanged

    Dim qty As Int16 = 0
    Dim cb As CheckBox


    For Each cb In GroupBox8.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
        If cb.Checked Then
            qty += 1
        End If
    Next

    If qty = 2 Then

        For Each cb In GroupBox8.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
            If Not cb.Checked Then
                cb.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    Else

        For Each cb In GroupBox8.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
            cb.Enabled = True
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

it just doesn't work. The groupbox's name is groupbox8 and it has 6 checkboxes on it. I need to select two checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a lot your CheckedChanged event handler using a bit of Linq

```
Private Sub AllBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' Get all checkboxes in the groupBox8
    Dim checks = groupBox8.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
    ' Count how many are checked
    Dim cnt = checks.Where(Function(x) x.Checked).Count()

    If cnt < 2 Then
        ' Enable all, avoid an if and don't care if already enabled
        For Each c In checks
            c.Enabled = True
        Next
    Else
        ' Disable all except the two checked...
        For Each k In checks.Where(Function(x)  Not x.Checked)
            k.Enabled = False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, Linq is intimidating at first, but once you grasp the concept of a sequence being enumerated through an expression that produces another sequence, all the pieces start falling in place.

Comment: Ya but it's neither fast nor easy to read and ends up adding more object code than the classic methods.. just my opinion though,